# Good practice way to output / insert post data

Tags: php, string, sanitization

Is there benefit over another or difference between

```
$start = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($_POST['shours'], $_POST['smins'], 0, $_POST['smonth'], $_POST['sday'], $_POST['syear']))));
```

and

```
$end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['hours'])), htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['mins'])), 0, htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['month'])), htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['day'])), htmspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['year']))));
```

I'm using to insert PDO prepared `execute($array(containing above strings and some others)` or bindparams statements if only few parameters.
Above lines are also output back to user if insert success.

I'm not sure if u need to do:

```
$output = htmlspecialchars($output); 
echo $output;
```

or is below equal ?

```
htmlspecialchars($output);
echo $output;
```

So $output is from now on safe to use?

Comment: 'htmlspecialchars' does not manipulate the input-parameter in situ (it does not take a reference as parameter, which would be necessary for that), so you need to assign the result to the/a variable. But follow Ghulam Alis advice/hints/explanations in his/her answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using PDO Prepared statements the query is generally safe. By generally I mean if you are binding the parameters and not using them directly in the query.

For example if this is your query: "INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES(:name)" and you bind :name with the user input. This is the safe practice.

However if you use this query "INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('$User_Input_Directly')". Now this is unsafe as the user input could contain the end of quotes and manipulate the query.

**htmlspecialchars** is not build to protect the variables in query. It is only used to convert special characters into HTML entities. For example if you don't want to convert any HTML codes in the input then you can use this code, but that does not means it will give you any protection within the query as it will not convert quotes unless you use ENT_QUOTES as flag. For test you can execute these two codes in your php file and see the difference:

```
$Var = "<b>Hello World</b>";
echo $Var; //without htmlspecialchars the text will become bold
echo htmlspecialchars($Var); //the text will show as it is without html bold format.
```

So don't use htmlspecialchars when you want to use the variable in query. Instead use PDO prepared statements or use mysql_real_escape_string.

**When outputting the variables htmlspecialchars will be protective against XSS and Javascript attacks.**